# Wildfly datasource does not connect to MySql database

Tags: java, mysql, jboss, wildfly, connector-j

I am completely new to Wildfly/JBoss so i am clueless what to do, i am sitting on this problem since yesterday noon. 
I am trying to use the mysql-connector-java-8.0.20.jar as the connector and my Wildfly version is wildfly-19.0.0.Final.
So the deployment on the server seemed to work fine, but whenever i try to add the datasource and test the connection i am getting this error:

```
"WFLYJCA0040: failed to invoke operation: WFLYJCA0047: Connection is not valid"
```

log/ Server throws:

```
2020-06-19 12:47:04,231 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources] (MSC service thread 1-7) WFLYJCA0001: Bound data source [java:jboss/datasources/MySqlDS]
2020-06-19 12:47:04,353 WARN  [org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.pool.strategy.OnePool] (External Management Request Threads -- 1) IJ000604: Throwable while attempting to get a new connection: null: javax.resource.ResourceException: IJ031084: Unable to create connection
    at org.jboss.ironjacamar.jdbcadapters@1.4.20.Final//org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.local.LocalManagedConnectionFactory.createLocalManagedConnection(LocalManagedConnectionFactory.java:345)
    at org.jboss.ironjacamar.jdbcadapters@1.4.20.Final//org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.local.LocalManagedConnectionFactory.getLocalManagedConnection(LocalManagedConnectionFactory.java:352)
    at org.jboss.ironjacamar.jdbcadapters@1.4.20.Final//org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.local.LocalManagedConnectionFactory.createManagedConnection(LocalManagedConnectionFactory.java:287)
    at org.jboss.ironjacamar.impl@1.4.20.Final//org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.pool.mcp.SemaphoreConcurrentLinkedDequeManagedConnectionPool.createConnectionEventListener(SemaphoreConcurrentLinkedDequeManagedConnectionPool.java:1326)
    at org.jboss.ironjacamar.impl@1.4.20.Final//org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.pool.mcp.SemaphoreConcurrentLinkedDequeManagedConnectionPool.getConnection(SemaphoreConcurrentLinkedDequeManagedConnectionPool.java:499)
    at org.jboss.ironjacamar.impl@1.4.20.Final//org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.pool.AbstractPool.internalTestConnection(AbstractPool.java:1067)
    at org.jboss.ironjacamar.impl@1.4.20.Final//org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.pool.strategy.OnePool.testConnection(OnePool.java:93)
    at org.jboss.as.connector@19.0.0.Final//org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.common.pool.PoolOperations$TestConnectionInPool.invokeCommandOn(PoolOperations.java:240)
    at org.jboss.as.connector@19.0.0.Final//org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.common.pool.PoolOperations$1.execute(PoolOperations.java:97)
    at org.jboss.as.controller@11.0.0.Final//org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractOperationContext.executeStep(AbstractOperationContext.java:999)
    at org.jboss.as.controller@11.0.0.Final//org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractOperationContext.processStages(AbstractOperationContext.java:743)
    at org.jboss.as.controller@11.0.0.Final//org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractOperationContext.executeOperation(AbstractOperationContext.java:467)
    at org.jboss.as.controller@11.0.0.Final//org.jboss.as.controller.OperationContextImpl.executeOperation(OperationContextImpl.java:1413)
    at org.jboss.as.controller@11.0.0.Final//org.jboss.as.controller.ModelControllerImpl.internalExecute(ModelControllerImpl.java:429)
    at org.jboss.as.controller@11.0.0.Final//org.jboss.as.controller.ModelControllerImpl.lambda$execute$1(ModelControllerImpl.java:246)
    at org.wildfly.security.elytron-private@1.11.2.Final//org.wildfly.security.auth.server.SecurityIdentity.runAs(SecurityIdentity.java:289)
    at org.wildfly.security.elytron-private@1.11.2.Final//org.wildfly.security.auth.server.SecurityIdentity.runAs(SecurityIdentity.java:255)
    at org.jboss.as.controller@11.0.0.Final//org.jboss.as.controller.ModelControllerImpl.execute(ModelControllerImpl.java:246)
    at org.jboss.as.domain-http-interface@11.0.0.Final//org.jboss.as.domain.http.server.DomainApiHandler.handleRequest(DomainApiHandler.java:212)
    at io.undertow.core@2.0.30.Final//io.undertow.server.handlers.encoding.EncodingHandler.handleRequest(EncodingHandler.java:72)
    at org.jboss.as.domain-http-interface@11.0.0.Final//org.jboss.as.domain.http.server.DomainApiCheckHandler.handleRequest(DomainApiCheckHandler.java:93)
    at org.jboss.as.domain-http-interface@11.0.0.Final//org.jboss.as.domain.http.server.security.ElytronIdentityHandler.lambda$handleRequest$0(ElytronIdentityHandler.java:62)
    at org.wildfly.security.elytron-private@1.11.2.Final//org.wildfly.security.auth.server.SecurityIdentity.runAs(SecurityIdentity.java:313)
    at org.wildfly.security.elytron-private@1.11.2.Final//org.wildfly.security.auth.server.SecurityIdentity.runAs(SecurityIdentity.java:270)
    at org.jboss.as.controller@11.0.0.Final//org.jboss.as.controller.AccessAuditContext.doAs(AccessAuditContext.java:254)
    at org.jboss.as.controller@11.0.0.Final//org.jboss.as.controller.AccessAuditContext.doAs(AccessAuditContext.java:225)
    at org.jboss.as.domain-http-interface@11.0.0.Final//org.jboss.as.domain.http.server.security.ElytronIdentityHandler.handleRequest(ElytronIdentityHandler.java:61)
    at io.undertow.core@2.0.30.Final//io.undertow.server.handlers.BlockingHandler.handleRequest(BlockingHandler.java:56)
    at io.undertow.core@2.0.30.Final//io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:376)
    at io.undertow.core@2.0.30.Final//io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:830)
    at org.jboss.threads@2.3.3.Final//org.jboss.threads.ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.run(ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.java:35)
    at org.jboss.threads@2.3.3.Final//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor.safeRun(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1982)
    at org.jboss.threads@2.3.3.Final//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.doRunTask(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1486)
    at org.jboss.threads@2.3.3.Final//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1377)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:835)
    at org.jboss.threads@2.3.3.Final//org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:485)
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: The server time zone value 'Mitteleurop?ische Sommerzeit' is unrecognized or represents more than one time zone. You must configure either the server or JDBC driver (via the 'serverTimezone' configuration property) to use a more specifc time zone value if you want to utilize time zone support.
    at deployment.mysql-connector-java-8.0.20.jar//com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:129)
    at deployment.mysql-connector-java-8.0.20.jar//com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:97)
    at deployment.mysql-connector-java-8.0.20.jar//com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:89)
    at deployment.mysql-connector-java-8.0.20.jar//com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:63)
    at deployment.mysql-connector-java-8.0.20.jar//com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:73)
    at deployment.mysql-connector-java-8.0.20.jar//com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:76)
    at deployment.mysql-connector-java-8.0.20.jar//com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:836)
    at deployment.mysql-connector-java-8.0.20.jar//com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:456)
    at deployment.mysql-connector-java-8.0.20.jar//com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:246)
    at deployment.mysql-connector-java-8.0.20.jar//com.mysql.cj.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:197)
    at org.jboss.ironjacamar.jdbcadapters@1.4.20.Final//org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.local.LocalManagedConnectionFactory.createLocalManagedConnection(LocalManagedConnectionFactory.java:321)
    ... 35 more
Caused by: com.mysql.cj.exceptions.InvalidConnectionAttributeException: The server time zone value 'Mitteleurop?ische Sommerzeit' is unrecognized or represents more than one time zone. You must configure either the server or JDBC driver (via the 'serverTimezone' configuration property) to use a more specifc time zone value if you want to utilize time zone support.
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:500)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:481)
    at deployment.mysql-connector-java-8.0.20.jar//com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:61)
    at deployment.mysql-connector-java-8.0.20.jar//com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:85)
    at deployment.mysql-connector-java-8.0.20.jar//com.mysql.cj.util.TimeUtil.getCanonicalTimezone(TimeUtil.java:132)
    at deployment.mysql-connector-java-8.0.20.jar//com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeProtocol.configureTimezone(NativeProtocol.java:2120)
    at deployment.mysql-connector-java-8.0.20.jar//com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeProtocol.initServerSession(NativeProtocol.java:2143)
    at deployment.mysql-connector-java-8.0.20.jar//com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.initializePropsFromServer(ConnectionImpl.java:1310)
    at deployment.mysql-connector-java-8.0.20.jar//com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectOneTryOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:967)
    at deployment.mysql-connector-java-8.0.20.jar//com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:826)
    ... 39 more

2020-06-19 12:47:04,356 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (External Management Request Threads -- 1) WFLYCTL0013: Operation ("test-connection-in-pool") failed - address: ([
    ("subsystem" => "datasources"),
    ("data-source" => "MySqlDS")
]) - failure description: "WFLYJCA0040: failed to invoke operation: WFLYJCA0047: Connection is not valid"
```

As i said, i an new, so please dont expect to much existing knowledge about wildfly.
Thanks in regards!

Comment: The server timezone is invalid. Either update the timezone on MySQL or pass the timezone as parameter in the JDBC URL.

Comment: Per the stack trace: `The server time zone value 'Mitteleurop?ische Sommerzeit' is unrecognized or represents more than one time zone. You must configure either the server or JDBC driver (via the 'serverTimezone' configuration property) to use a more specifc time zone value if you want to utilize time zone support.`

Comment: Where exactly can i change the setting? Google sais, that there should be a my.conf file, but i dont know where to find it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Solution 1: Pass the timeZone using the database url on the connector

Your database url should look like jdbc:mysql://ip_address:port/port?serverTimezone=UTC
You can change to your timezone of choice

#### Solution 2: Change your MySQL configuration file

On ubuntu the configuration file is my.cnf. For ubuntu 18.04 the file's location is /etc/mysql/my.cnf
Add a line as below:
default-time-zone = '+01:00'
Set to your preferred time zone 
Restart your MySQL server.

Comment: The second solution worked for me ! Thank you very much :)

Answer (score 0):

Yes thanks, solution 2 worked! 
In my case the my.cnf-File was called "my", so that was kinda confusing. I dont know, why it is called like that.
I found the file at this path:
C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0